# Why would Firefox access the windowsupdate.log?

Tags: firefox, windows-update

Just updated to Firefox 8. The next download I did, Comodo Defense plus, catches Firefox attempting to write to the Windowsupdate.log. Why would it possibly be trying to access this file? Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Can you check your Addons - plugins and extensions, and see if you have any Microsoft addons installed?  Perhaps even the Windows Update addon?  It is likely that an MS addon is writing to the log rather than firefox itself.

Comment: There are two plugins from Microsoft. Silverlight and the Windows Media Player dll. I don't do updates via web interface, I run WSUS here at work. Either of the previously mentions plugins are not likely in my opinion unless anyone has something to show otherwise?